# Custom field not showing in Admin page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I created a cutom user model for my project. And the extra fileds I created is not showing in the Admin page.

I just see the standard fields and none of the extra made.
I can't fins anything online about what i'm missing.

My model for customuser:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    mobilephone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ["surname", "firstname", "email", "mobilephone"]


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Also, the field 'First name' and 'Last name' is not the same field as my custom user model.
[image]

Comment: Maybe a missing field problem with CustomUserChangeForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created a custom User Admin derived from Django's `UserAdmin`

You need to modify the `fieldsets` attribute in it.

This is how it is defined in `UserAdmin` class.

```py
fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
```

In order to add your field under `Personal info` fieldset, like the following

```py
fieldsets = (
        ...
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('firstname', 'surname', 'email', 'mobilephone')}),
        ...
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # ----
    fieldsets = (
       (None, {'fields': (
         # in build
         ('first_name',),
        ('last_name',),
        ('username',),
         # custom
         ('surname'),
       )
    )
```

More https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets